# How To pad Audio stream with silence

Tags: c#, naudio

I have an `ISampleProvider` I want to pad with 10 seconds of silence, how would I achieve this in NAudio?

```
  var songDelayed = new AudioFileReader(filePath_1);

    //Delay "songDelayed" by 10 secs
    //What do I do here?

    myDirectSoundObj.Init(songDelayed);
    myDirectSoundObj.Play();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `OffsetSampleProvider`

```
var songDelayed = new AudioFileReader(filePath_1);


var offset = new OffsetSampleProvider(songDelayed);

offset.DelayBy = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
// or if you don't have latest NAudio source:
// offset.DelayBySamples = songDelayed.WaveFormat.SampleRate * 
//     songDelayed.WaveFormat.Channels * 10;


myDirectSoundObj.Init(offset);
myDirectSoundObj.Play();
```