# How to add pauses in the audio of a SpeechSynthesizer output file?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I am looping the same text 5 times, but the text repeats too fast. I have tried adding periods before my string and after, and it dosn't add a pause after each sentence, for example

```
// update the status
UpdateStatus("Generating audio");

// create the wav file
ss.Volume = 75;
ss.SelectVoice("VW Julie");

// Generate the Audio file
ss.SetOutputToWaveFile(audio);
int i = 0;
var pronounce = "This is a test sentence"
while (i < 5)
{
    ss.Speak(".................." + pronounce);
    i++;
}
```

My created file doesn't add a pause to my wav file, it's just continous. How can I add a long pause between each sentence?

Comment: I am assuming that you are working with `SpeechSynthesizer` object. Why not use pause method? The usage and examples for pausing and resuming is give at the bottom of this article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572477(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: What is the var `ss`?

Comment: Pause only works when I am playing it, not saving which is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @randommman this might point you in right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838479/how-to-pad-audio-stream-with-silence

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Thread.Sleep(10000);` for example, to wait seconds...

Just add

```
using System.Threading;
```

to your list of `using` statements and pick the duration that suits you.

```
using System.Threading;

{
    ss.Speak(".................." + pronounce);
    i++;
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to the actual audio file that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert pause by using speakSsml() like below.

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace SSMLExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a SpeechSynthesizer object for English speech synthesis
            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            // Set the SSML text
            string ssmlText = "<speak version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis\" xml:lang=\"en-US\">I am <break time=\"1000ms\"/>a human</speak>";

            try
            {
                // Synthesize speech using SSML
                synthesizer.SpeakSsml(ssmlText);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while synthesizing speech: " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Speech synthesis completed.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```